# Unable to get result back to onActivityResult() of calling activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I have a use-case where my Activity A will start other Activity B of some SDK, here Activity B  is a transparent activity hence allowing me to still interact with A. Now from A, I start another activity C by using startActivityForResult() and from C, I am sending back the result using setResult(). But I am not able to get the result back in onActivityResult() of A.

Point to be noted here is that Activity B from other SDK is having launchmode set as "singleTask" in androidManifest file.

How I can get result back from C to A in this case?

Here is the code used in Activity A to start C :

```
var intent: Intent =Intent(context, ActivityC::class.java)
startActivityForResult(intent,1009)
```

In Activity C setting result like this :

```
val returnIntent = Intent()
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)
finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is okey. But the thing is, that when you start activity b, then in your stack, activity b will be the last to be created, so when you then start c, the result from c goes to b instead of a.

Try launching c before b to make sure this is the issue.

Comment: I cannot change the flow of activity creation, I am also not able to get result back to B as well in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If Activity B is from another SDK and you can't control the navigation flow, then you have to store the data somewhere and check that `onResume()` function of Activity A.